# R: what is NA_character_?

Tags: r

```
>dput(dummy)
c(NA, "MGM", NA, "M", NA)

>dummy
[1] NA    "MGM" NA    "M"   NA 

>ifelse(dummy == "NA", 0, 1)
NA  1 NA  1 NA
```

I have a character vector, and I want to replace the `NA` values with 0 and everything else as 1. However, I have no idea what exactly these `NA` characters are? As you can see above they're not `"NA"`. When I tried `dput(dummy[1])` I get `NA_character_`. What can I do to get the ifelse statement to recognize those `NA`s?

Comment: Use `is.na` to detect NAs. `ifelse(is.na(dummy), 0, 1)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In R, nothing is ever equal to `NA` (how could anything be `==` to `NA` when we don't know what it is?) but it is possible to be equal to "NA" (the character value with two letters as in the abbreviation for North America. `NA` (no quotes)is a special missing value placeholder and actually comes in different flavors, one for each atomic class.

```
 ?NA   # where you can read about the other flavors of NA
 NA_character_
#[1] NA
```

As C_Z_ notes you can and should use is.na() to detect these special (non)-values. Your `ifelse` test would have returned a 0 in any position where the character vector had a value of "NA", but a test for equality using "==" to `NA` will always return NA.

```
> dummy == NA
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

These might have been less puzzling:

```
> ifelse( is.na(dummy), 0, 1)
[1] 0 1 0 1 0
> 0+!is.na(dummy)   # using 0+... to coerce logical to numeric
[1] 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: `NA_character_` (and others) exist because `NA` is a logical value, and you can't mix types in vectors.  For example, you can't have a literal `NA` in a character vector, because that would require the character vector have a non-character element (the logical `NA`).  That's why there is `NA_..._` for the other atomic types that support missing values.

Comment: Other typed NA values are: NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and NA_character_. See the [R Documentation for NA](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NA.html).